# JSON post method in php

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I don't get what do I do wrong when I try to get my values from post method from angular to php, it seems that everything is correct but then I am not able to see any values to postman/return the correctly.[image: this is what I get]

this is my php method with all my attempts:

```
public function created()
{
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_string_in_array = array($json);
    $json_array =json_decode($json_string_in_array[0]);
    var_dump($json_string_in_array);
    var_dump($json_array);
    //return $json_array;
  //  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
   // $data = json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  //  $request = json_decode($data);
  //  var_dump($data);
  //  return $data;
  //  return $request;
  //  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //$obj = json_decode($json);
     // get the raw POST data
    // $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    // this returns null if not valid json
    // return response()->json($rawData);
    //  DatabaseModel::DatabaseModel($json_array);
}
```

what I am trying to do is get that data and then send it to DatabaseModel in order to add it to database.

Comment: What is your enctype ?

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

this is my post method in angular: `function PostReview(JSONObject) {
        if(JSONObject!=null){
             $http({ 
                 url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
                 method: "POST",
                 data: JSONObject,
                 headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;", "Accept": "application/json" } });
       console.log(JSONObject);
        }
        }`

Comment: `$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); var_dump($json);` returns what?

Comment: In postman I get: string(0) ""
In browser Network response: string(80) "{"name":"test","surname":"testsurn","email":"ss@gmail.com","review":"text text"}"

And I think I understood, that it gets correct data and I just don't now how to access it correctly to see in postman, right?

Answer (score 0):

First you header, `content-type`, should be `application/json`. Are you manually setting the headers in angular? I am pretty sure angular will detect (or at least it is the default) the content type if its not set so in your case it would be `application/json`

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json);
$name = $request->name;
$email = $request->email;
# etc
?>
```

Comment: Anguular:`function PostReview(JSONObject) {
        if(JSONObject!=null){
             $http({ 
                 url: 'http://localhost:8000/creation',
                 method: "POST",
                 data: JSONObject,
                 headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;", "Accept": "application/json" } });
             }
        }`
I get this trying your example:(
` 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\GuestBook\\Book\\lumen\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\DatabaseController.php', 30, array('json' => '', 'request' => null))`

Comment: you are still setting your content type incorrectly

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/creation. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. I get this error then..